# How to handle Angular $http result in a Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am using a Angular factory, service and a controller. I use the service to $http get data from a url, send it to the factory who then handles the response data and sends a object to the controller:

**Service:**

```
module.exports = function($http, $q){
  return {
    getOptions: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({ method: "GET", url: AppAPI.url + 'acf/v2/options/' })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.reject(status);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
};
```

**Factory:**

```
module.exports = function(optionsService){
  var options = {};
  var getOptions = optionsService.getOptions();

  getOptions.then(function(items){
    options = items;
  });

  return options;
};
```

**Controller:**

```
module.exports = function($scope, $http, optionsFactory){

  console.log(optionsFactory);

};
```

But the Factory returns an empty options to the controller. How would you assign the items from the promise to the options object which get's returned to the controller?

**UPDATE**

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bff46aw3/4/)

Would appreciate the help :)

Comment: The promise looks like it should be returned inside the `.success` or `.error` functions. Try moving the return statement inside both.

Comment: I have updated with a fiddle

Comment: Why use a factory to pass data back from a service to the controller? Just use the service directly in the controller and assign the result

Comment: I can cut out the factory. But is it possble for the service to handle the result? i dont want to handle the result in the controller

Comment: @Sebas What do you mean by handle - if it's doing something to the data then just pass it to another function in the service - a controller should really just be used to display the data that comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing

```
var getOptions = optionsService.getOptions();
// to
var getOptions = optionsService.getOptions;
```

If you created a plunkr/fiddle, that would help a bit.

Comment: Hi, it then says getOptions is not a function. I have updates Q with fiddle